# Outlook Appointment Ribbon Button Events

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, add-in

I'll try be specific with an example but I could be talking about any ribbon button event in Outlook 2010. When you go to create an appointment, the new appointment dialog opens with a ribbon along the top where you can save, invite attendees etc. There is also a button so you can create a recurrence pattern. I'm wondering if it is possible to implement an event handler to respond to the recurrence button click event?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to replace the `GroupAppointmentMoreOptions` group. You should download the [XLS spreadsheet containing the existing Outlook 2010 control IDs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627) (*see OutlookAppointmnentItemControls.xlsx*).

To replace the Ribbon Group, see [this website which describes how to properly modify existing Ribbon Groups](http://www.rondebruin.nl/xmlribbongroups.htm).